# How to reload on source file change when using gulp and flask?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, gulp, gulp-watch

I'm using gulp to run tasks, with the final task being launching flask using gulp-shell.

How does one get gulp tasks to be rerun and flask to reflect these changes on file change?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is currently not happening - Is flask/python code changes not being reflected?

Comment: @Anarci In an ideal situation, I'd be able to run gulp and start my flask app with a single command.  Then gulp would rerun and the browser would refresh on file change.  Right now I've got gulp-watch taking care of rerunning on file change, but I've got to start gulp and flask with two separate commands (different than above) and refresh the browser manually.

Comment: @conner.xyz: were you able to fix this issue..even im trying to understand..any inputs will be very useful.